# Listen zoom event in ChartJS

Tags: java, charts, vaadin

I use ChartJs wrapper for Vaadin framework and I need to update chart with data when user makes either zoom in/out or panning. Is it possible to somehow catch an event when user scrolls a mouse wheel and get min/max values of X-axis (where datetime labels are displayed) to pass them to backend and fetch new data from database?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add to chart options the code below

```js
options:{
  pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'x',
      speed: 10,
      threshold: 10,
      onPan: function({chart}) {
          // Do something
          console.log(`I was panned!!!`);
      }
  }
}
```